# Infimum and supremum of $\frac{x}{y^2+1}+\frac{y}{x^2+1}$ for $x+y=1$ and $x,y\in{\mathbb{R}^{+}}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I've been trying to find the infimum and supremum of $$\frac{x}{y^2+1}+\frac{y}{x^2+1}$$ for $x+y=1$ and $x,y\in{\mathbb{R}^{+}}$

My only idea was to represent $x$ and $y$ as $\sin^2{z}$ and $\cos^2{z}$ but that didn't help me a lot. I'd like if someone could provide some sort of a hint for this. Thanks.

Comment: Having only thought for about 3 seconds... have you tried expressing the whole thing in terms of one variables using the constraint $x+y=1$ and then taking the derivative to find maxes and mins?

Comment: To be clear, the "3 seconds" comment wasn't meant to be rude. It meant that if that doesn't work, it's because I only thought for 3 seconds. Ha.

Comment: Yep, tried that, got lost in the calculations :(

Comment: @Trancendental: well I'm fairly certain that's what is expected of you here, although the current answer is also very good. I encourage you to try it again, take your time, and slowly write everything out. Perhaps I will post a solution here. Would that be helpful?

Answer (score 2):

It can be shown that when $x + y = 1$, $f(x, y) = \dfrac{x}{y^2 + 1} + \dfrac{y}{x^2 + 1}$ reduces to $g(u) = \dfrac{2 - 3 u}{2 - 2 u + u^2}$, where $u = x y \in [0, 1 / 4]$.  Can you try to find bounds for $g(u)$ in this situation?

Comment: Actually, yes , that does simplify the problem.